How to resolve the generic form of a JsonConverter in System.Text.Json
I know that this issue is more a question of the limitations of C# generics than it is a question about .NET Core (8.0) JSON Serialization but it is driving me crazy.
When getting 'underneath the hood' of System.Text.Json, for example, when writing Custom Converters, the accepted way to retrieve a 'registered' JsonConverter is to call options.GetConverter(...) passing the type to convert.
The method returns the non-generic JsonConverter type even though all converters are generic, i.e. of type JsonConverter<T>. The non-generic type cannot be used for serialization/deserialization because it doesn't have the required Read/Write methods.
This has led me to 'throwing the baby out with the bath water' and abandoning the built-in converter registry and JsonSerializerOption.GetConverter(...) in favour of a Dictionary which maps types to type-specific 'serializer' or 'deserializer' Delegates which perform the necessary Read/Write operations.
These can be written so as to use the existing converter registry as follows:
This is a pain, but relatively organized and easy to do.
That said, it seems like overkill.
So my question, or questions, is/are:

Is there a better solution to this old chestnut?

Is it really impossible in generic typing to resolve a non-generic base type to its generic equivalent even when this is the implemented form without declaring the type explicitly as in the code fragment below (i.e. using a Type rather than <T>), or is C# generics being over-restrictive here?



private delegate void Serializer(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializerOptions options);

private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Serializer> _Serializers = new Dictionary<Type, Serializer>
{
    { typeof(string), SerializeStringValue }
};

private static void SerializeStringValue(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    var converter = options.GetConverter(typeof(string));
    if (value is string stringValue && converter is JsonConverter<string> stringConverter)
    {
        stringConverter.Write(writer, stringValue, options);
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteNullValue();
    }
}


JsonConverter has a variety of non-generic internal methods like TryWriteAsObject() but MSFT does not make them public so casting to JsonConverter<T> is your only option for calling the converter directly.

That being said if you're not going to cache the converter it would be better just to call JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options).  Internally JsonSerializer.Serialize() will just get the converter and call those internal methods so you are unlikely to get better performance by calling the converter directly.

Also calling JsonConverter<T>.Write() doesn't necessarily work as expected for some built-in converters.  For instance the Write() method of the built-in converter for double does not respect the setting JsonNumberHandling; see the comment thread for this answer for details.  Calling JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options) avoids that problem also.

Does that answer your question?

Thanks for your comments @dbc. I decided to proceed down a management/caching route for serialization. There are a couple of additional reasons for doing this: 1) I want to 'register' scoped collections of converter instances on a modular basis, so need to maintain a container of JsonSerializerOptions instances that I can use 'on-demand'. 2) For BSON (MongoDB) serialization as well, I want to avoid repeated deserialization of JSON/BSON data where it is known that the underlying data has not changed. As I already have a Repository pattern in place that wraps the underlying data collection, adding a cache mechanism is relatively straight forward. These two aspects combine quite neatly.
